# JxBrowser escape key not dispatched

Tags: javascript, java, keyboard, jxbrowser

When I dispatch an escape key from Java to JxBrowser, it is not received.  But I can successfully send numeric keys, the enter key, alpha keys, etc.  The two simple test cases below show my problem (read misunderstanding).

```
    KeyTyped keyTyped = KeyTyped.newBuilder().setKeyCodeValue(13).build();
    browser.dispatch(keyTyped);   // JavaScript handler receives enter keystroke
    
    KeyTyped keyTyped = KeyTyped.newBuilder().setKeyCodeValue(27).build();
    browser.dispatch(keyTyped);   // JavaScript handler DOES NOT receive escape keystroke
    
// JS handler
$(document).on('keypress.lineItemSelected', this.handleKeyboardPress.bind(this));
```

Comment: ESC is not a text symbol, so please try dispatching KeyPressed and then KeyReleased instead of KeyTyped: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/browser.html#dispatch-keyboard-events

Answer (score 1):

`ESC` is not a text symbol. Sending only `KeyTypes` is not correct way of simulating keyboard input. Please try dispatching `KeyPressed`, `KeyTyped`, and then `KeyReleased` as shown in the example at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/browser.html#dispatch-keyboard-events

```
private static void dispatchKeyEvent(Browser browser, char character, KeyCode keyCode) {
    KeyPressed keyPressed = KeyPressed.newBuilder(keyCode)
            .keyChar(character)
            .build();
    KeyTyped keyTyped = KeyTyped.newBuilder(keyCode)
            .keyChar(character)
            .build();
    KeyReleased keyReleased = KeyReleased.newBuilder(keyCode)
            .build();

    browser.dispatch(keyPressed);
    browser.dispatch(keyTyped);
    browser.dispatch(keyReleased);
}
```